# Need Assistance with This Simple Python Code

Tags: python

Here is my code & this is my error : AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'strptime

```
#Trying to calculate how many days until a project is due for
import datetime
project = input('When is your project due for Please specify mm/dd/yyyy ')

deadline = datetime.datetime.strptime(project, '%m/%d/Y').date()

days = project - deadline

print(days)

print(days.days)
```

Thank You in advance #KOH

Comment: import datetime is on a completely different line

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: I am using version 3.4.3

Comment: Are you sure this is the exact code in your script?

Comment: I'm not sure how you're getting _that_ error, but separately, it's `'%m/%d/%Y'`, not `'%m/%d/Y'`. Also `days = project - deadline` won't work, because `project` is a string and `deadline` is a `date` object. And if it did work, it would always be 0 days, since they represent the same date.

Comment: @cyphase yes i'm sure this is the right code in my script And then how would I calculate this. this is basic stuff here

Comment: I don't see how you're getting that error if that's your exact code. How are you running the script?

Comment: @cyphase with the regular 3.4.3 Shell I feel like i have the code right I judt don't know why am getting error.

Comment: The reason I asked is because your code doesn't give me the error you're getting; it gives me different errors, which I've already mentioned.

Comment: Try running this script: `import datetime; print(datetime); print(datetime.datetime); print(datetime.datetime.strptime)`

Comment: @Cyphase I went to go eat dinner and that code gave me this <module 'datetime' from 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\datetime.py'>
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
<built-in method strptime of type object at 0x1DB99D18>

Comment: Also @Cyphase I have another code very similar and it works just fine ... here it is

import datetime
current_date = datetime.date.today()

import datetime
a = input('when is your bday? Please specify mm/dd/yyyy ')
b = datetime.datetime.strptime(a, '%m/%d/%Y').date()

days = b - current_date
print(days)
print(days.days)

Comment: Now _replace the code in that same script file_ with your code in the question.

Comment: @Cyphase not sure what this error means but I copied and pasted my code into the filr i was running my other code on and it gave me this instead of my other errors. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/wtf p1.py", line 6, in <module>
    b = datetime.datetime.strptime(a, '%m/%d/Y').date()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\_strptime.py", line 500, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)

Comment: It's because you're missing a `%` in `'%m/%d/Y'`. But you're no longer getting that `AttributeError` anymore. Is this script in the same directory as your first script was? Is it possible you have a `datetime.py` in the same directory?

Comment: @Cyphase YESSSS!!! that was it man the %Y thanks for your help! the little things....  I've been starring at my computer for 6 hours no wonder I didn't catch that mistake! +10000 credits for you

Comment: That wasn't the initial issue, but you're welcome :). I'll write it up in an answer.

Comment: @KohNetwork, answer posted.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need something like this:

```
import datetime
project = input('When is your project due for. Please specify mm/dd/yyyy ')

deadline = datetime.datetime.strptime(project, '%m/%d/%Y').date()

delta = deadline - datetime.datetime.now().date()

print(delta.days)
```

Using Python3 there is no errors with datetime:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime("08/11/2015", "%m/%d/%Y").date()
datetime.date(2015, 8, 11)
```

Comment: I've done this and when running with the shell 3.4.3 it gave me an answer of 6 for 11/22/2015 I dont think it's 6 days till november 22nd.

Comment: Update code 'import datetime
current_date = datetime.date.today()

import datetime
a = input('When is your project due for Please specify mm/dd/yyyy ')
b = datetime.datetime.strptime(a, '%m/%d/Y').date()

days = b - current_date
print(days)
print(days.days)'

Comment: That dosn't work but this does 'import datetime
current_date = datetime.date.today()

import datetime
a = input('when is your bday? Please specify mm/dd/yyyy ')
b = datetime.datetime.strptime(a, '%m/%d/%Y').date()

days = b - current_date
print(days)
print(days.days)'

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you were getting that `AttributeError`, but I guess we resolved it in the comments. You were also getting an error because your formatting string was missing a `%`. And once you fix that, you would get an error saying you can't subtract a `date` from a `str`.

Even with all the errors fixed, what the code is doing isn't what you're trying to do. It looks like you're trying to subtract the user-provided date from itself, but I'm guessing you want to subtract today's date from the user-provided date, in order to get the number of days until the user-provided date.

Here's the fixed code, with some formatting and other changes thrown in.

```
from datetime import datetime

deadline_str = input('When is your project due? Specify mm/dd/yyyy: ')

deadline = datetime.strptime(deadline_str, '%m/%d/%Y').date()

days_till_deadline = (deadline - datetime.today().date()).days

print("{0} days till the project is due.".format(days_till_deadline))
```

Comment: Very happy to had ur help!

Comment: @KohNetwork, happy to help :). Assuming then that this answers your question, could you accept so the question will be marked as answered?

Answer (score 0):

So this is the code written by me and it works...

```
#todays date programme
import datetime
currentDate = datetime.date.today()
#currentDate is date which is converted to string with variable current in the format dd/mm/yyyy
current = datetime.datetime.strftime(currentDate, '%d/%m/%Y')
#input statements
userInput = input('Please enter your project deadline (dd/mm/yyyy)\n')
print()
##prints...
print("Today's Date is "+current)
print()
print("Your project deadline is " + userInput)

#userInput is a string which is converted to date with variable Input
Input = datetime.datetime.strptime(userInput, "%d/%m/%Y").date()
##Calculating remaining days
remainingDays = Input - currentDate
remainingDays = remainingDays.days
print()
print('The days remaining for deadline are '+str(remainingDays)+' days')
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess it's something like this. 
Because here we had to import the date time first cos we working with the date. 
Then we had to get the current date in order to be able to get the project deadline.

```
import datetime

current_date = datetime.datetime.now() 

user = input('Enter the days left for your project: ') 
deadline = datetime.datetime.strptime(user, '%d%m%Y').date() 

days_left = deadline - current_date.date() 

print(days_left.days)
```